# Curl data being returned by function

Tags: php, curl

For example the following code

```
<?php
function test($ip)
{
$ch = curl_init("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=".$ip."&position=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$ipData=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return "Hi";
}
$result=test("64.233.160.0");
print $result;

?>
```

Im expecting it to print "Hi", but it has the data returned by the curl then "Hi". Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<?php
function test($ip)
{
$ch = curl_init("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=".$ip."&position=true");
// Here add this..
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
/// ....
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$ipData=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return "Hi";
}
$result=test("64.233.160.0");
print $result;

?>
```